# Confirm date format

Tags: php

How can I compare if an inserted date is in this format (`yyyy-mm-ddThh-mm-ss`)?
I receive this:

```
$start_date= $_GET['start_date'];
```

And I want to check the format.
Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8003446/php-validate-iso-8601-date-string

Answer (score 5):

you can use `DateTime::createFromFormat` to be sur it is Ok. 
If this method return false, your format is not good, if not, you get a correct date to deal with

```
$date = dateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d\Th-i-s',$date);
if($date === false)//incorrect
```

Answer (score -3):

I think this is useful to you >

```
<?php   
 function testDate( $value )   
 {   
  return preg_match( ''^\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4}$'', $value ) )   
 }   

 testDate( '21/11/1999' ); // -> true   
 testDate( '3/9/2008' ); // -> true   

 testDate( 'a/04/2003' ); // -> false   
 testDate( '28-01-2000' ); // -> false   

 testDate( '99/13/1978' ); // -> true   
?>
```