# Is there a way to validate a ISO8601 date in Symfony?

Tags: validation, symfony, iso8601

How would I go about validating a date is ISO8601, specifically RFC3339? Do I need to write some custom Regex to do this?

Comment: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/DateTime.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think, that the regular expression is the solution as the Validator constraints does not support this.

[Here is the regular expression for that](http://regex101.com/r/lM1bQ7/1)

Is it a form input you want to validate?

Answer (score 2):

As a matter of fact, the only way I know, except the proposed regexp, is to add its own callback validator:

```
        ->add('occured_at', 'text', [
            'constraints' => [
                new Assert\NotBlank,
                new ASsert\Callback(function($date, $context) {
                    if (false === \DateTime::createFromFormat(\DateTime::ISO8601, $date)) {
                        $context->addViolation("$date is not at ISO8601 format.");
                    }
                })
            ],
        ])
```

Comment: `\DateTime::createFromFormat(\DateTime::ISO8601, $date)` is not always correct cf. http://stackoverflow.com/a/21260686/377645

Answer (score 2):

**ONLY WITH SYMFONY 3.1**

You can use

```
@Assert\DateTime(format="Y-m-d\TH:i:sO")
```

See : http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/DateTime.html

Format for ISO8601 "Y-m-d\TH:i:sO" ;

http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php

**EDIT 1 :**

You can use directly the format "c", shortcut for ISO 8601 format

(ISO 8601 date (added in PHP 5) : http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Comment: This is not working for me, it says that format option is not allowed.

Comment: In which version of symfony are you ?

Comment: Got an answer in github, it needs version 3.1 or higher. But this option is so obvious that I cant even imagine how could this validator exist without it.

Comment: Works in Symfony 5.3 too.

Comment: The 'c' format does not work with Symfony Validator v5.4, because of PHP bug: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=51950&thanks=3