# Add optional Parameter to Base Route in Laravel

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, optional-parameters

I am trying to add optional Parameter to my home route which is

```
Route::get('/{selectDate?}', [
    "as" => "/",
    "uses" => "PublicController@index"
]);
```

and my index Function is like

```
public function index($date = null)
    {
       if($date!=null){
       //some line of codes
       }

   }
```

and i trigger optional parameter by a select list on change function which is

```
$(function() {
            $('#selectDate').on('change', function() {
                window.location.href = '{{route("/")}}' + "/" + this.value;
            });
});
```

Now issue is this when I hit any other link from home page they all going in index function not in there own written functions. 
Need help regarding this issue.

Comment: Please show us your `routes/web.php` file

Comment: @Sebastian `routes/web.php` is already posted on first block

Comment: @MayankPandeyz this is only one route. I want to see the whole file.

Answer (score 1):

Any string will match an optional parameter, there are 2 options to solve this problem.

You could put this route at the bottom of your `web.php` route file, routes will be matched on a first-come-first-serve base thus it will only fall through to this route if no other route will match the given url.

Your second option is using regex to define the optional parameter of which more information can be found [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing#parameters-regular-expression-constraints).
In short you can use

```
Route::get('/{selectDate?}', [
    "as" => "/",
    "uses" => "PublicController@index"
])->where('selectDate', '/^(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})T(\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})Z$/');
```

After this the `selectDate` should always match a pattern as `01-01-2000`.
*regex untested and copied from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8003798/2976077) SO answer*

Answer (score 1):

In such cases you have to check the route parameter using [Regular Expression Constraints](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/routing#parameters-regular-expression-constraints) like:

```
Route::get('{user_tipe}/event', 'admin\EventC@index')->where('user_tipe', 'admin');
```

where route will match `admin` and if it match then specific route will work, otherwise not.

Comment: this is helpful